# Is it possible to extract the firmware of an Arduino BLE or IoT board wirelessly?

Tags: wireless, firmware, arduino-nano-ble, arduino-nano-33-iot

I've looked at previous questions regarding sketch extraction and know that it is possible to extract the hex code from an Arduino board using avrdude from the command line.

However, I want to see if the following is possible:

1. Connect to Arduino 33 IoT board
2. Extract onboard Firmware as a hex file
3. Disconnect from Arduino 33 IoT board.

I understand that getting the initial source code is not possible, but I am in particular looking to just get the hex code in a wireless manner. If it is not possible via the Arduino 33 IoT board, is there any Arduino board with which this can be done? Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the firmware can read its own application section, but it won't send it to you wirelessly (or via any interface) if such a feature isn't implemented in that firmware. If you were to implement the firmware yourself, you can do (almost) anything. But if it is a third party firmware, this will not be possible.

The reason this works with arduinos and avrdude is, because firmware up- and download are implemented in hardware (ISP, works without a bootloader).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just to be sure, you're saying that for any Arduino device the methodology I stated in my initial question is just not possible unless I code it myself into the firmware beforehand?

Comment: @TjHasan Yes, that's it...